# Average in Pivoting table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, average

I wanted to calculate the average of company score and property score by ignoring the 0's for the below picture (pic1) in pivot table

[image: Pic1]

When I average the column in pivot table it includes the 0's as gives the average as shown in below picture (pic2) :

[image: Pic2]

Expected average is 65.53 for company and 75 for property in pivot average.
Kindly help in getting the expected results in pivot table

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle that:

1. Remove all zero-values from your data used to create the PivotTable
2. Apply a filter to the PivotTable to remove items with zero (select the column right of the PivotTable and create Autofilter > then select custom; set that the filter involves only values > 0)
3. Right click on the field (depending on the fact if the field is a cloumn or a row field) where the zero appears, choose settings. and specify that you want a particular value (in this case the value 0) omitted from the PivotTable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace NULL with ="", then it will work.